# Continuity of a solution to a pde

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, continuity

If $u(x,t)=1$ for $x>t$ and

$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{1+\tau^2}$ for $x<t$  with $\tau=\frac{\sqrt{1+4x(t-x)}-1}{2x}$

how can I check that $u$ is continous at $x=t$?

If I sub in $x=t$ for $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{1+\tau^2}$

I get an answer of $1$, which agrees with the value for $x>t$, but I do not feel I have been rigorous enough.

Comment: Why is this tagged PDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant function $1$ is trivially continuous. $1/\left(1+\tau^{2}\right)$ is also continuous on $x<t$ assuming $t\geq 0$ (note that the only discontinuity occurs at $\tau=i$ which is precluded by $x<t$). Therefore, as you pointed out, we need only check to see that the functions agree at $t=x$. You have already done this.

Comment: Why can I check continuity $x=t$ when the function is not defined there?

Comment: Ah, good point. I didn't realize that the function is not defined at $x=t$. To establish continuity, you are going to have to extend the function to that point. At the very least, you can take solace in the fact that this is the only way to extend the function to a continuous one.

If you got this from solving a PDE, then surely you are looking for a function in a particular space (e.g. continuous functions). Therefore, ultimately you will need to take this continuous extension.